# How to add an XML declaration prolog with encoding to XML in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2016

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[ENTETE]
FOR XML PATH('ENTETE'), TYPE
```

This is the result:

```
<ENTETE>
     <CIB_DECLARANT>10057</CIB_DECLARANT>
     <Type_Fichier>DECLARATION_TCN</Type_Fichier>
     <DATE_DECLARATION>03122019</DATE_DECLARATION> 
</ENTETE>
```

I want to add the XML encoding like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<TCN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ENTETE>
       <CIB_DECLARANT>10057</CIB_DECLARANT>
       <Type_Fichier>DECLARATION_TCN</Type_Fichier>
       <DATE_DECLARATION>03122019</DATE_DECLARATION> 
    </ENTETE>
```

Comment: The XML in your desired results is not  well-formed. You've added a processing instruction and TCN start element but have no TCN closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server holds XML data type internally as UTF-16. And because of it, it strips any XML prolog.

That's why if you need an XML declaration prolog, you need to use `NVARCHAR()` data type.

Please see below.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @ENTETE TABLE (CIB_DECLARANT INT, Type_Fischier VARCHAR(30), date_declaration DATE);
INSERT INTO @ENTETE (CIB_DECLARANT, Type_Fischier,  date_declaration) 
VALUES (10057, 'DECLARATION_TCN', '2019-12-03');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- just to see
SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @ENTETE
    FOR XML PATH('ENTETE'), TYPE
).query('<TCN  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
{
    for $x in /ENTETE
    return $x
}

</TCN>');

DECLARE @prolog NVARCHAR(100) = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>'
   , @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- real deal
SET @xml = @prolog + TRY_CAST((SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @ENTETE
    FOR XML PATH('ENTETE'), TYPE
).query('<TCN  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
{
    for $x in /ENTETE
    return $x
}

</TCN>')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

-- final XML with the prolog as NVARCHAR() data type
SELECT @xml;
```

> Output (indented for the human eyes only)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<TCN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ENTETE>
      <CIB_DECLARANT>10057</CIB_DECLARANT>
      <Type_Fischier>DECLARATION_TCN</Type_Fischier>
      <date_declaration>2019-12-03</date_declaration>
   </ENTETE>
</TCN>
```

Comment: Zakaria, please touch base with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't strip the XML prolog.  Instead, when a prolog exists and the encoding is explicitly set to UTF-8, it raises an error "XML parsing: unable to switch the encoding".